# Tourist visa from Swiss embassy in New York

Tags: visas, switzerland

The embassy said that I didn't need to appear in person because I had a previous Schengen visa from the French embassy. So I mailed in an application on October 31. The tracking number from the post office says the embassy received the package on November 1st.

It's been 7 days and I haven't gotten a confirmation email from the embassy. Has anyone mailed in an application before? Did you receive an email from the embassy saying they have received it?

(I emailed the embassy yesterday, haven't heard from them yet. Maybe someone who went through this can share their experience?)

Comment: I think you may need to clarify your question. What exactly are you applying for? Why? What is your country of citizenship? I’m just a bit confused because an American traveling to Switzerland for tourism purposes shouldn’t need a visa.

Comment: not a US citizen, I do need a visa. and I emailed embassy about whether I need to go in-person (appointment and etc.) They told me "no need, just mail your application in.) I'm asking other people who also mailed in application .. do we get an email confirmation from the embassy that they have received it? how do we check application status if there is no communication? (what type of visa? I would happy to answer. tourism (9 days) but I feel the answer shouldn't be different.)